# Sticky Notes - share with other users?

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

I realize that by default Sticky Notes posts only to the users desktop creating the note, but is it somehow possible to tweak it so that a note can be placed onto the Public Desktop, thereby making it visible to every user on that computer?

Maybe some sort of Registry edit?

I would be satisfied with having the ability to create a Sticky and it appear commonly on all users desktops (and they be able to create and have it appear as well)

But .. the ideal setup would be the ability to create my own Sticky that only appears on my own desktop, OR have the option to be able to, for example, drag and drop a Sticky into the Public Desktop folder for all to see (and this again being a feature all users have the ability to utilize)

Comment: What is preventing you from dragging-copying it to the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

You will find the (unfortunately binary) sticky notes data file StickyNotes.snt under %appdata%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\ (usually expands to C:\Users\some.user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes).

The Public folder will not be of any help here and the only option I see is to copy/paste the file itself among target user AppData directories (tested).
This will erase any existing note, since you will need to overwrite existing StickyNotes.snt file.
You may want to automate it a little bit (a user Sticky Notes being the reference to copy upon session start or on demand, through a script.

Cheers!